# How to style this <hr> with image and text in the middle?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

So I am styling this horizonal line with the idea of image and text in the middle and got stuck. How could I align the image on the left side of "TEXT" and not under it? Here's the link to demonstrate the current state:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJWJad

Appreciate all the help.

```
.horizontal__rule--modified {
  line-height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  border: 0;
  color: #666666;
  text-align: center;
  height: 1.5em;
  opacity: 0.7;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 16px;
  &:before {
    content: url(http://www.metalguitarist.org/forum/images/mgtwitter.png);
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
  }
  &:after {
    content: attr(data-content);
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: red;
    background-color: #fcfcfa;
  }
}

<hr class="horizontal__rule--modified" data-content="TEXT">
```

Comment: Just a quick question. Is my answer is what you are expecting or is it something different?

Comment: It's neat, thanks...but how could I add the image next to text this way..?

Comment: just add the image next to it... The twitter image right?

Comment: No self closing element can carry a pseudo element; i.e. `<img>`, `<input>`, `<br>`, `<hr>`, etc ... @PraveenKumar has the right approach if you want to use generated content.

Comment: HTML semantic is overrated anyway.

Comment: @Smithy http://output.jsbin.com/debusesohe This way? Source: http://jsbin.com/debusesohe/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @PraveenKumar oh...great!! thank you!

Comment: @Smithy Check my updated ultimate answer. LoL.

Comment: Hey sorry, forgot to thank @Jayx for editing my answer. `:D`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you don't need a `<hr />` at all here. You can just use pseudo elements and make it possible:

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-weight: normal;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
h1 span {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
}
h1::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Hello</span></h1>
```

If an image is needed for this like having [a twitter icon](http://output.jsbin.com/debusesohe), you can use: [Source](http://jsbin.com/debusesohe/edit?html,css,output):

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14pt;
}
h1 span {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
}
h1::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>
    <img src="http://www.metalguitarist.org/forum/images/mgtwitter.png" alt="" />
    Hello
  </span>
</h1>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Answer (score 2):

Another solution apart from Praveen's is to use flex-box.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="text">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.line {
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
}
.text {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jdgqmmv5/